# HMAC-SHA512 bug in my code

Tags: c++, hmac

I would greatly appreciate, if you could help me with this c++ implementation of HMAC-SHA512 code, I can't seem to find why it gives a different hash than online converters. (The SHA512 is working just fine.)

Code (based on wikipedia):

```
#include <iostream>
#include "sha512.h"

using namespace std;

const unsigned int BLOCKSIZE = (512/8); // 64 byte

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc!=3)return 0;
    string key = argv[1];
    string message = argv[2];

    if(key.length() > BLOCKSIZE){
        key = sha512(key);
    }
    while(key.length() < BLOCKSIZE){
        key = key + (char)0x00;
    }

    string o_key_pad = key;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < BLOCKSIZE; i++){
        o_key_pad[i] = key[i] ^ (char)0x5c;
    }

    string i_key_pad = key;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < BLOCKSIZE; i++){
        i_key_pad[i] = key[i] ^ (char)0x36;
    }

    string output = sha512(o_key_pad + sha512(i_key_pad + message));

    cout<<"hmac-sha512: \n"<<output<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: surely the `while (key.length() < BLOCKSIZE)` should be above the `key = sha512(key);` (and why would that be conditional?).  I think you need to work through what it's actually doing, the data it's operating on etc. methodically....

Comment: It's better to add traces to track the `key`/`message` and others' values, to see which line gets the unexpected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out the BLOCKSIZE is incorrect.

According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2, sha-512's block size is 1024 bits, which 128 bytes.

So simply change the code to

```
const unsigned int BLOCKSIZE = (1024/8); // 128 byte
```

You get the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the quick responses, the problem was with the hash function(sort of).
The sha512 output was converted to hex before return, so the "sha512(i_key_pad + message)" did not answer what I was expecting. (And also the blocksize was 1024)